# Make an touchesbegan event to uiwebview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiwebview, touchesbegan

I hope you can help me and first sorry for my bad english. 
I want to tap an specify point (x/y) on an uiwebview in iOS. I have tried something with

`(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }`

and

`(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
 [webview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  }`

But i does not work yet. The uiwebview is a subview of uiview, i think.

Can you help me?

Greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Just call a javascript function like this:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:"/*JS Code goes here*/"];
```

instead of `/*JS Code goes here*/` 
type a java script code to do what you want to do by firing the click on the x,y position you want. I am assuming you can control the web page content if not please comment and I will add more complex solution.

If you want to call a function that is defined inside an iframe that is included inside your page content you need to define two functions:

1- JS Function inside the iframe page that appears as source for the iframe tag name this function iFrameFunc()

2- JS Function in the parent HTML page name it parentFunc()

3- parentFunc should get handle to the iframe by id or class selector and call the iframeFunc()

4- Obj-c would call the [UIWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString] to the parentFunc

Comment: Sorry that´s no opinion because the position is in an iframe and i can`t change these. 

But thank´s!

Comment: Are you trying to set focus on certain element?

Comment: What do you mean? via js?

Comment: from iPhone UIWebView you can call JavaScript function inside your page or execute some JavaScript code directly using the method I have in the answer above.

Comment: Yes, but I can not click on an object that´s loading by an iframe because of cross-site-scripting

Comment: Actually you can call any JS function inside the iframe if you want, I can do that from the parent. so please check my answer I will edit it for you

Comment: That's really good! But i can't Control The iframe content. You say, that i have to add an js function to the iframe page but thats not possible.

Comment: I am sorry that I could not help you :(

Comment: I have to say thank you to you for your attention and your good piont :)!

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed `UIWebView` and just "leeched" onto its gesture recognizers in subviews 2 levels deep (you could go recursively but thats enough for iOS6-7).
Then you can do whatever you want with the touch location and gesture recognizer's state.

```
for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in view.gestureRecognizers) {
        [recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:)];
    }
    for (UIView* sview in view.subviews) {
        for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in sview.gestureRecognizers) {
            [recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEvent:)];
        }
    }
}
```